# Java Map Read File Store in Map first letter as a key and value for the words

Tags: java, android, string, dictionary

I'm trying to get all the strings inside the Map by Key which is the first letter of each word in the Map but keep removing the duplicates and I am left with only a few words.

```
public class Search {

    private static void searchHashForLetterKey() throws FileNotFoundException {
            Map<Character, String> charCount = new HashMap<Character, String>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

            String word = "and";

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                char firstChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                charCount.put(firstChar, scanner.next());
            }

            // Print out each of the values.
            for (Map.Entry<Character, String> entry: charCount.entrySet()) {
                char character = entry.getKey();
                String count = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(character + ": " + count);
            }

            if (charCount.containsKey(word.charAt(0))){
                System.out.println("KEY FOUND");
                if(charCount.containsValue(word.trim())){
                    System.out.println("Word found is: " + word);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your word is not found in the example: " + word);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Key Not Found: " + word);
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println();

            try {
                searchHashForLetterKey();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The file is a word.txt file which contains dictionary of english words same as this one: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt

Here it is a working example but still not as intended still can't check for contains() for the word.

```
public static void searchforWords() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String match = "add";

    List<String> words = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("cat", "ball", "bat", "cup", "add", "ant"));
    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    for(String word: words){
        String firstChar = String.valueOf(word.charAt(0));
        if (map.get(firstChar) == null){
            map.put(firstChar, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(word)));
        }
        else{
            map.get(firstChar).add(word);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map + "\n");

    if (map.containsKey(String.valueOf(match.charAt(0)))){
            System.out.println("GOT KEY");
        if (map.containsValue(match)){
            System.out.println("GOT VALUE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` can only have one value per key. To work around this you can create a `Map<Character, List<String>>` instead of `Map<Character, String>`. Java 8 allows you to do this pretty elegantly in a single statement:

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("wordsEn.txt"))
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0)));
```

Comment: I know here it is the example that is working but still can't check if the work is contained

Comment: @Izvorski can you describe what exactly you're trying to do? I don't understand this comment.

Comment: MultiMap can be used for this from guava:https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap

Answer (score 0):

Define `HashMap` with Character as `key` and `ArrayList<String>` as `value` and store all name list in start char match `HashMap` key :

```
private static void searchHashForLetterKey() throws FileNotFoundException {
            Map<Character, ArrayList<String>> charCount = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>>();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

            String word = "and";

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                char firstChar = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                ArrayList<String> list;
                if (charCount.containsKey(firstChar)) {
                    list = charCount.get(firstChar);
                } else {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                list.add(scanner.next());
                charCount.put(firstChar, list);
            }

            // Print out each of the values.
            for (Map.Entry<Character, ArrayList<String>> entry : charCount.entrySet()) {
                char character = entry.getKey();
                ArrayList<String> list = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println(character + ": " + list.size());
            }

            if (charCount.containsKey(word.charAt(0))) {
                System.out.println("KEY FOUND");
                ArrayList<String> list = charCount.get(word.charAt(0));
                if (list.contains(word.trim())) {
                    System.out.println("Word found is: " + word);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your word is not found in the example: " + word);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Key Not Found: " + word);
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println();

            try {
                searchHashForLetterKey();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is working now i did check some stuff and it is was some problem with the IDE. Thanks you for the help! Still there are some items that it cannot find like "work" you can try to search for that it will not find it.

Comment: Can you please provide some cases or is there any lower and upper case char issue ?